Find all $f(x)$ such that $x f''(x) + f'(x) \ge 0$
Let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R^+}$ with $a < b$ and $f(x) : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Either numerically or (if possible) analytically, find the set of all $f(x)$ that satisfy the following conditions: 

$(a,f(a)), \, (b,f(b)), \, (a,f'(a)), \, (b,f'(b))$ are known constraints and all positive.
$f'(x) > 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \forall \hspace{0.5cm} x \in [a,b]$
$x \cdot f''(x)+f'(x) \ge 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \forall \hspace{0.5cm} x \in [a,b]$

Analytical approaches: 
First, I considered condition 3) and set $x \cdot f''(x) + f'(x) = g(x)$ where $g(x) \ge 0$ is an arbitrary function. One should be able to solve this expression analytically, but need to make an assumption on $g(x)$ to analytically solve it, meaning I would restrict myself to only a subset of possible solutions for $f(x)$. To keep it general, I expanded  $ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n $ and plugged it into condition 2) and 3) to obtain:
condition 3: $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1}\, (n+1) n \, x^n+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1}n \, x^n \ge 0 \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1} \, (n+2)n \, x^n \ge 0$
condition 2:$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}\, n \,x^n \ge 0$

However, here I would not know how to continue so I tried to find a numerical approach...
Numerical approach: 
My idea was to generate random functions numerically and then check if they randomly happen to satisfy the constraints. I deemed cubic splines with the nodes $(a,f(a)) \, (b,f(b))$ and one intermediate node $(d,e)$ to be suitable for this setup. The algorithm was to randomly generate the intermediate node $(d,e)$ between the two boundary nodes, create a cubic spline passing through these points and then check if that spline fulfills all the three constraints. However, interestingly they all fail to satisfy the third constraint... 
Does some of you see a way for a numerical approach that helps me find all possible $f(x)$ that satisfy these constraints (without any more restrictions) for the given boundary conditions?

The inequality  $(3)$can be written as "$xf'$ is monotonic increasing and differentiable." So given any monotonic increasing differentiable function $g,$ you get $$f(x)=C+\int_a^x\frac{g(t),dt}t.$$

You get: $C=f(a),$ $f'(a)=\frac{g(a)}a,$ $f'(b)\frac{g(b)}b,$ so we can work out from the inputs $g(b),g(a), C$ and $\int_a^b\frac{g(t),dt}t.$ (2) means $g$ must be non-negative.

Can you explain in more detail how you can rewrite inequality (3) to such a statement? Also I dont see how your f(x) solves the constraint.

Okay thank you guys for clarifiying. I do understand now that $xf'$ is monotonically increasing. But how do you reach the formula for $f(x)$ that @ThomasAndrews came up with?
